# Send outbox message without having type

Tags: c#, masstransit

We are using MassTransit with RabbitMQ and part of our implementation includes an outbox pattern.
Now i'm trying to create a docker container whose only purpose is to dispatch messages from outboxes in several databases.

The container gets a list of connection strings to the various databases and then starts to dispatch messages from their outboxes.

Currently we store the following information in our outbox (with examples):

- MessageType: SomeNamespace.SomeType, SomeContract
- MessageBody: {"SomeProperty":"MyValue"}
- TransmitMethod: Send/Publish
- QueueName: SomeQueueName

My question is if it's possible to dispatch these messages without having access to the contract types?

I can add more information to the table if needed to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [look at how the MassTransit message scheduler support for Quartz.NET](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/Scheduling/MassTransit.QuartzIntegration/ScheduledMessageJob.cs#L67) captures and ultimately sends the message on the transport. In this case, it's saving the serialized message from the transport and reloading the JSON into the message body at serialization time.

You might also find useful details in the [relational outbox](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/pull/2234) draft PR.